# Compare two tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with identical definition:

```
create tabA (
user_id int,
contact boolean,
promote boolean
);

create tabB (
user_id int,
contact boolean,
promote boolean
);
```

I want to compare two columns `contact` and `promote` and see if there is any discrepancy in row data. For example:

row from tabA: `1,T,T`
row from tabB: `1,T,F`

So there is discrepancy now I want to catch that and select only those rows where they are not equal.

Comment: You would have to define what happens with NULL values, which are obviously allowed according to your table definitions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tabA, tabB 
WHERE tabA.user_id = tabA.user_id 
AND (
 tabA.contact != tabB.contact 
 OR
 tabA.promote != tabB.promote
);
```

Comment: you got it !! appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

As long as there can be NULL values, you need to use [null-safe operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html):

```
SELECT user_id, a.contact AS a_contact, a.promote AS a_promote 
              , b.contact AS b_contact, b.promote AS b_promote 
FROM   tabA a
JOIN   tabB b USING (user_id)
WHERE  a.contact IS DISTINCT FROM b.contact OR
       a.promote IS DISTINCT FROM b.promote;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Postgres' record comparison capability:

```
select *
from taba a
  full join tabb b using (user_id)
where a is distinct from b;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find differences in table content you should compare 3 column's values of next query:

```
select (
        select count(*) from (
            select * from a
            union
            select * from b
        ) m
    ) merged,
    (select count(*) from a) in_a,
    (select count(*) from b) in_b;
```

If value in `merged` column is not equal to value in columns `in_a` and `in_b` then the content of table `a` and `b` has at least one difference.