# How does `USING` keyword work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, sql-using

I am confused with the `USING` keyword which is used to join two tables in postgres. I first saw it in another SO post [Compare two tables in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469800/1418007). I checked the manual for postgres [2.6. Joins Between Tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html).
I can't understand how postgres identified the `user_id` to be joined (in the SO post).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html) states:

> The USING clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name for the joining column(s). It takes a comma-separated list of the shared column names and forms a join condition that includes an equality comparison for each one. For example, joining T1 and T2 with USING (a, b) produces the join condition ON T1.a = T2.a AND T1.b = T2.b.

So simply said, in this case both tables have the column `user_id` and the join is done based on them.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong section of the manual. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @NandakumarV The documentation could use a bit of cross-linking or enhancement, I also had to do some digging to actually find the place where this is explained

Answer (score 1):

A `USING` clause can be used with an [EXECUTE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in PL/pgSQL language(`LANGUAGE plpgsql`) for a function, procedure and `DO` statement.

For example, you can use a `USING` clause with an `EXECUTE` statement in the PL/pgSQL function `my_func()` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(my_age INT, my_id INT) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING my_age, my_id;
END;                                              -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```